# Reflection to load an object of a class and run the object as a new thread from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection

I have been studying Reflection in Java for a few days now.

I have 2 classes, SimulatorInstance and SimulatorInstanceThread. I am trying to load an instance of SimulatorInstance using reflection and run that object as a new thread using Runnable interface from SimulatorInstanceThread.

I have tried to load the SimulatorInstance class using Classloader:

ClassLoader simInstance = SimulatorInstance.class.getClassLoader();

and tried running it as a new thread. But it doesn't work. I know this is probably very basic. But can someone point out what is the mistake here?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do you got the ClassLoader but I don't think that that is correct.  Take a look at [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) to understand a bit better how to create classes that you've found through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

"doesn't work" doesn't give any hint.It is hard tell what the issue could be with the limited information you provided. Could you provide details of your classes, the error message and so on?

Comment: For one it says the Constructor Thread(ClassLoader) is undefined. So, I tried casting it to runnable. But then I get a cast exception. @Yohannes